# Does structuralism have preference for thinking through structures?

Tags: postmodernism, structuralism, deconstruction

Structuralism states we are governed by narrow cultural structures.

I believe post-modernism and post-structuralism acknowledge the existence of this structures as well.

Is the difference in the attitude towards the structure? Like post-modernism wants to deconstruct some category like gender, while structuralism adhere to the natural categorization.

Please correct me, if I made any wrong assumptions.

Comment: Yes. [Structuralism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuralism) is "the methodology that implies that elements of human culture must be understood by way of their relationship to a broader system. It works to uncover the structures that underlie all the things that humans do, think, perceive, and feel."

Comment: Thanks. But what about post-modernism, as far as I understand it also believes in the existence of cultural structures, it just considers them bad. Is the difference in the value judgement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate the difference using two writers usually held up as examples of the respective categories, Claude Lévi-Strauss (Structuralist) tries to demonstrate that the same universal structures, especially [binary oppositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_opposition), underlie all human thought across different societies. Michel Foucault (Poststructuralist) acknowledges that all societies are governed by a structure ([episteme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episteme#Foucault_(%C3%A9pist%C3%A9m%C3%A8))), but doesn't use a universal formula in order to uncover it; thus his studies tend to highlight the unusual.